# Button Styling on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I'm designing a dashboard on wpf and I have to make buttons like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVFVJ.jpg

This is a button; there is an image in the middle, a content in the top right corner and a content in the bottom.

How can I do ?

Comment: I guess the image is also variable. Meaning you need 3 "content" properties and a button has 1. You need 2 more content-like dependency properties Either inherit button or use attached properties. Grab the template for button and arrange 2 more content presenters or just textblocks in it. Bind their content/text to your new dp.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button Width="50" Height="50">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <!-- The order matters here, since you want your image at the bottom -->
                                <Image Source="Images\YourImage.png"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Top" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Bottom"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: thanks Ivan. that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Button 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Background="Blue">

    <StackPanel Width="120" Height="120">
        <Label
            Content="243"
            FontSize="11"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Foreground="White"/>

        <Image 
            Source="sample-icon.png"
            Width="64"
            Height="64"/>

        <Label
            Content="Other text"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Foreground="White"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Button>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks AmRo. It is working.